# Prevent form submit if field value is false

Tags: jquery, forms, events, submit, preventdefault

I am trying to create some code to use jQuery to prevents the users from submitting a form if the value in a text field is different from 50. The form submit work great, but I am having some issues with the jQuery code to prevent submitting.

My HTML Code:

```
<form name="vehicleRegFrm" id="vehicleRegFrm" action="" method="post">
    <input name="samp" id="samp" type="text" />
    <input name="sbtAddCarFrm" type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

Here is the problematic jQuery code:

```
$('sbtAddCarFrm').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

    if ($('samp').val() != 50) {
        $('vehicleRegFrm').submit();
    } else {
        alert("your message");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  $("#vehicleRegFrm").submit(function(){
         if ($('#samp').val() != 50) {
             alert('form will not be sent')
             return false;
         }
         else {
             alert('form will be sent')
             return true;
         }
  })
```

if the user write 50 the form will be sent
if the user write a different value nothing will be sent

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, just tried by no success, form is still submitted no matter what is the input in `samp` field.

Comment: I tried this on my local and it works. I am pretty sure there's a third party detail that I ignore.
things to confirm:
1) jquery library is correctly called
2) jQuery code must be placed after html code
3) try to run this apart in a new page to avoid any unexpected conflict

Comment: Problem was that I have placed the jQuery before the HTML. Placing it after worked! Thank you for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: Was searching on google for this, Found it, +1ed it! ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="sbtAddCarFrm"]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($('#samp').val() != 50) {
        $('#vehicleRegFrm').submit();
    }
    else {
        alert("your message");
    }
});
```

note that in this code you can only submit if the value is NOT 50, which is different than you had in your question!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, just tried by no success, form is still submitted no matter what is the input in `samp` field.

Comment: still no luck, the form is submitted everytime.